# OpenSource tool to model message flows between user-defined functions/blocks

Tags: graph, uml, nodes, data-modeling

I am new to stackoverflow, and to modeling in general. I am neither and expert programmer so I am looking for an OpenSource tool to model the following:

I would like to create a graph-like model (nodes and links between the nodes) to represent the message flow across the "network". The situation is: There are different types of messages, and nodes which behave differently according to the message received. I.e. Node 1 sends message type A to Node 2, this triggers that Node 2 sends message type B to Node 3. However, if Node 1 sends message type C to Node 2, this will trigger that Node 2 sends message type D to Node 4.

I do not need very high level detail on message types nor node functionality, but I need to be able to configure the nodes' "routing" capabilities.

In the end I would like to measure how many Type A, B, C message pass by Nodes 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

I am a little lost in terms of what kind of modeling suits this problem and in consequence what kind of tool fits best to the modeling.

Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See
» http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html
and
» http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-examples.html
and
» http://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-overview-diagrams-examples.html
and
» http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools
for some links that should help you learn the basic terms practically
and
» `Control Nodes` - http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_11/column1/
and
» `Object Nodes` - http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_01/column3/
for some theory

---

UML is a broad topic » http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/

---

<sub>Some alternative Google term is: `Data Flow Diagram`</sub>

Comment: Thank you xmojmr for your response. I considered UML, but I don't know if it is possible to model the "randomness" I need.

E.g. for this flow:
A -->   message="Hello" -->  B
                             B --> message = "A is here" --> C
                             B <--message = "Ok Im coming"<--C 
A <-- message="C is here"<-- B

But C, might (randomness) not be available, and there is no reply to B, after which B retries the 2nd msg, and after some time, sends a msg to A saying "C is not here" for example.

Not sure if this is possible with UML

Thanks again

Comment: @cristinik yes it is possible in UML. For modeling "randomness" see [Combined Fragment in UML Sequence Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html) and [Decision Node in UML Activity Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this thoroughly. I am not an expert in UML but I assume that I should define a UML sequence for each node and within each node, for each type of message; an then somehow, put it all together. Thanks again.

Comment: @cristinik yes, you should **start drawing**. UML sequence diagram with `alt` fragments and UML activity diagrams are the language features you should embrace first. For some quick start with sequence diagrams take a look at online tool https://www.websequencediagrams.com/. Once you get over the paper&pencil phase then http://www.modeliosoft.com/ is weird but open source and http://www.visual-paradigm.com/ has a free community edition. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for the established "thank you" rules